# add two columns of a row in apache pig

Tags: apache-pig

Find out top 5 country with Sum of bars and strips in a flag.

Input is :

**[image: strong text]**

I tried the below code1:

```
grunt> A =load 'mapreduce/flagdata.txt' using PigStorage(',') as (name: chararray, landmass: int, zon: int, area: int, population: int, language: int, religion: int, bars: int, stripes: int, colours: int, red: int, green: int, blue: int, gold: int, white: int, black: int, orange: int, mainhue: chararray, circles: int, crosses: int, saltires: int, quarters: int, sunstairs: int, crescent: int, triangle: int, icon: int, animate: int, text: int, topleft:chararray, botleft: chararray);
grunt> cnt = foreach A generate A.$0, (A.$7+A.$8);//(the same output even if used column name like A.name,A.bars)//
grunt> ord = order cnt by $1 desc;
grunt> lm = limit ord 5;
grunt> dump lm;
```

Actual output of code1:

```
ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output. 1st : (Afghanistan,5,1,648,16,10,2,0,3,5,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,green,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,black,green), 2nd :(Albania,3,1,29,3,6,6,0,0,3,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,red,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,red,red)
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.PigStatsUtil - 1 map reduce job(s) failed!
```

Code2:

```
grunt> cnt = foreach A generate A::$0, (A::$7+A::$8) as total;
<line 6, column 28>  Unexpected character '$'
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: <line 6, column 28>  Unexpected character '$'
grunt> cnt = foreach A generate A::name, (A::bars+A::stripes) as total;
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025: 
<line 6, column 25> Invalid field projection. Projected field [A::name] does not exist in schema: name:chararray,landmass:int,zon:int,area:int,population:int,langu
age:int,religion:int,bars:int,stripes:int,colours:int,red:int,green:int,blue:int,gold:int,white:int,black:int,orange:int,mainhue:chararray,circles:int,crosses:int,
saltires:int,quarters:int,sunstairs:int,crescent:int,triangle:int,icon:int,animate:int,text:int,topleft:chararray,botleft:chararray.
```

Expected output is:

Need to display the name of top 5 countries with sum(bars+stripes) is greater.(seperate column is just for reference)
[image]

I am getting different outputs and sometimes errors(***Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.***) while modifying the above code. Please help in obtaining sum of two columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the datatype of bars and stripes is int then just use '+'.SUM operates on columns.Also no need to group if the country list is unique.

```
cnt = foreach A generate name,(bars + stripes) as total;
ord = order cnt by $1 desc;
lm = limit ord 5;
dump lm;
```

Comment: it shows error as :         org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 0: Exception while executing (Name: Split - scope-181 Operator Key: scope
-181): org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException: ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output.

Comment: even after the change it shows the same error :ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.pigstats.SimplePigStats - ERROR 0: Scalar has more than one row in the output.

Comment: ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1025:Invalid field projection. Projected field [A::name] does not exist in schema:

Comment: @pavan can you post your entire script?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. updated the entire script that i tried.please let me know if any other info required.

Comment: @pavan is your file columns comma separated? does you file have column headers? Remove alias A i.e instead A.name use just name?

Comment: perfect @VK_217 .. thanks a ton...but why it gave error if we used alias..any idea pls?